# How to generate a new object array from another 2 arrays

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 arrays like [image: pic1] and [image: pic2], I want to generate a new array with 2 elements like pID and cNo. pID is getting from the first array and the cNO is from the second array. How to merge these 2 arrays like

```
newarr=    { 0: pID:970989, cID:'dfds'
             1: pID:970995, cID:'fgd',
             2: pID:971006, cID:'t765'}
```

Comment: your new array isn't an array. It looks like an object, but even still, if its an object it will give a syntax error. Please provide a valid output

Comment: if both always have the same length, you can iterate (for loop) one of them and produce a new array.

Comment: The expected output in the new Edits are still invalid object and will cause in syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your arrays are equal in length you can just loop over one of them and create a new array.

```
const newArray = pIDArray.map((pID, index) => ({ pID, CID: cIDArray[index] }));
```

Comment: It will create many objects in each iteration but expected output is different. downvoted...:(

Comment: I think that's what he wants because he says merge these two arrays... his expected output might be a syntax error.

Comment: it will create array of objects what the guy need ,so upvoted :)

Comment: Yes that is why i voted for closing instead of answering it.